# Is it possible to apply order by in view cart on GoCart Open source?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to change the order of the products displaying in the view cart page,Is it possible to apply order by query for products listing in view cart page in GoCart Open source Codeigniter Shopping Cart?

Comment: Have you found the code that is responsible for product listing?

Comment: no, its coming from go cart libraries.. thats why i asked is it possible or not? :)

Comment: Anything is possible. But you have to track (and debug) the code. Find the lines where query for product listing is made. Try to change it to fit your needs. If you get stuck, post relevant part of code with updated question or post new question. This way is so broad for anyone to help. Also you need to show us that you made effort in solving problem since nobody wants to write code for free, but many of people here (including myself) like to help on issues.

Comment: Read [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) how your question should look like and what else you need to do before asking. That article helped me a lot.